# Why tf.linspace() will return a long decimal number?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Today, I tried to equally split a number range into a number list with TensorFlow's `linspace` function, I found it return a very annoying result:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, 11))
```

The output:

```py
tf.Tensor(
[-3.         -2.4        -1.8        -1.1999999  -0.5999999   0.
  0.60000014  1.2000003   1.8000002   2.4         3.        ], shape=(11,), dtype=float32)
```

But if I use the same function in Numpy, it will show a more reasonable result:

```py
import numpy as np
print(np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, 11))
```

The output:

```py
[-3.  -2.4 -1.8 -1.2 -0.6  0.   0.6  1.2  1.8  2.4  3. ]
```

Why TensorFlow will return a number that has a long decimal, like `-0.5999999` not just `-0.6`?

Comment: Annoying in what sense? The `tf.linspace` returns a "Tensor" as compared to a numpy array being returned by `np.linspace`. Tensorflow library functions return tensors which are used in the "graph" created by tensorflow.

Comment: @Mohit you see that where should be -0.6, but tensorflow returns a -0.5999999

Comment: Those are just inaccuracies in floating point representations. Numpy likely does some truncation/rounding under the hood for "nicer" looking output, but the actual numbers should be the same in both cases.

Comment: @xdurch0 Ok, I get it, thank you very much.